# Android app sqlite database cannot dump in to android mobile

Tags: android, sqlite

I created database and table in sqlite database after that i can take thedatabaseoutside using file explore. And then i inserted some values into the table again i paste the database in same location in file explore .if i am run in emulator means it takes data from sqlite and populate listview in android mobile. after that the same app i put in mobile means it cannot take sqlite database.i think the sqlite database cannot dumped to the mobile while installing my app..please tell me the solution how to solve?

```
          This my database class


public Cursor queueAll() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT };
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor != null) {
        do {
            String keyid = cursor.getString(id);
            System.out.println(keyid);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return cursor;
}


private static class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(apptable);
        db.execSQL(souptable);
        db.execSQL(vegtable);
        db.execSQL(ricetable);
        db.execSQL(desserttable);
        db.execSQL(FoodMenutable);
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public long AddUser(String username, String password) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}

public boolean Login(String username, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor mCursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?",
            new String[] { username, password });
    if (mCursor != null) {
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

  }
```

please help me

Comment: put ur database in asset folder after inserting value in it and fetch from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter manually data in your database using your application because you can't modify or import database of your application from android mobile.

Comment: use insert(String content) like 'content = "insert into mainmenu name";' in your activity to insert in to your mobile database